# Regex to catch the parent element of an <li> tag

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Simply put I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Unorderd Item 1</li>
  <li>Unordered Item 2</li>
  <li>Unordered Item 3
    <ol>
       <li>Ordered Item 1</li>
       <li>Ordered Item 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Unordered Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking for a regular expression or some logic of that nature that replaces the `<li>` tag with something depending on what its parent list element is.

I can use straight up RegEx or I can use (more than likely my route here) the .Net System.Text.RegularExpressions class so:

Regex.Replace

Regex.Matches

<-- I know I could/should be using a HTML parser but this is being used in conjunction with a XSLT config doc. So using a Regex seems to be the best way to go. -->

Desired Output:

```
<ul>
   <Unordered>Unordered Item 1</Unordered>
   <Unordered>....</Unordered>
     <ol>
        <Ordered>......</Ordered>
        <Ordered>......</Ordered>
     </ol>
   <Unordered>.....</Unordered>
 </ul>
```

Comment: you want to replace with what..can you provide some sample output..also what have tried!

Comment: What I want to replace with isn't that important, what it gets replaced with depends on which type of list is its parent (e.g. the <li> tag can be: <OrderedList> or <UnorderedList>).

Comment: no one would be able to ans your question unless you provide us with some sample output for the above html..i have no idea about what you are asking..

Comment: Do not use regex to parse HTML!  It is **not** the best way to go!  Use the DOM!

Comment: You definitely don't want to use regex for this. You need a HTML parser -- an XML parser might also work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/47589

Comment: Are you using xslt to transform this, or what is meant by "in conjuction with"? You could probably use some XQuery update. Just stay away from trying to regex this, as mentioned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags. You can't parse (X)HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);

foreach (var li in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li"))
{
    if (li.ParentNode.Name == "ul") li.Name = "Unordered";
    if (li.ParentNode.Name == "ol") li.Name = "Ordered";
}

var newHtml = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Output:

```
<ul>
  <unordered>Unorderd Item 1</unordered>
  <unordered>Unordered Item 2</unordered>
  <unordered>Unordered Item 3
    <ol>
       <ordered>Ordered Item 1</ordered>
       <ordered>Ordered Item 2</ordered>
    </ol>
  </unordered>
  <unordered>Unordered Item 4</unordered>
</ul>
```

Comment: You win. Regex is a bad idea for this kind of parsing.